# Matplotlib graphs are bunching up when displayed

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook

I have 86 separate graphs in this image but they are bunching up. I apologize in advance about the short code snippet, but it's part of a long notebook. I hope it's enough to pinpoint the problem

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=43, ncols=2, figsize=(14, 7))
axes = axes.flatten()

index = list(range(1, 25))
synthetic = generated_data[np.random.randint(n_windows)]

idx = np.random.randint(len(df) - seq_len)
real = df.iloc[idx: idx + seq_len]

for j, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    pd.DataFrame({'Real': real.iloc[:, j].values,
                   'Synthetic': synthetic[:, j]}).plot(ax=axes[j],
           title=ticker,
           secondary_y='Synthetic', style=['-', '--'],
           lw=1)
sns.despine()
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: What did you expect?  (And that's not a sarcastic question.)  You asked for tight layout.  That's pretty tight.  ;)

Comment: You are putting 43 plots in 7 inches.  They are going to be small.